# Tridion Resolver not Resolving Linked Items

Tags: cme, 2013-sp1, 2011-sp1, custom-resolver

I'm seeing resolving behaviour in Tridion 2013 SP1 that's quite different than what I was used to seeing in 2011 SP1...

On one implementation, in 2011 SP1 I had a case where there were a bunch of interlinked components.  e.g. a promo component would link to an article, the article would be linked to from other components.  So this caused the usual avalanche of publish items.  I fixed that with a custom resolver by filtering out the unneeded items.

On another implementation, in 2013 SP1 we have an article component and a container component that holds articles.  I was expecting that if I publish an article, the containers that use this article would get published to, but no.  All I see in the "Items to Publish" list is the component itself.

So my theory is that at some point after 2011 sp1, the resolver logic was changed to not have the avalanche by default, rather the other way around.  Can anyone confirm/deny this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue is addressed with hotfix CME_2013.1.0.87280 available here: https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/hotfixes/SDL_Tridion_2013_SP1/index.aspx (login required, or contact Production Support).

A word of caution: we were about to build a Custom Resolver to address this having custom logic to pull the needed linked components in.  However, this would have locked us into subscribing to the defective behaviour (or at least the non-designed behaviour).  To minimize risks around backwards and forwards compatibility, I advise applying the hotfix and not building on top of defective behaviour.

Comment: "unpublishing" behavior will also be fixed with this hotfix I am guessing, meaning unpublish will trigger an unpublish of linked components (after this hotfix is installed)?

Comment: Be aware that similar erroneous behaviour also exists in XPM, and to fix that there is another hotfix (available on the same page) XPM_2013.1.0.88175: Component links are not resolved when publishing using "Finish Editing".