# How to publish all related linked component when a component is published

Tags: 2013, publishing

i have nested 3 linked component. For e.g. , component A linked to component B and component B is again linked to component C. Every time i make some changes in component C and publish , it doesn't republish linked component B and changes are not getting reflected on page. how does publish works for linked component? Is there any better way to organize the publish process for linked components?Please let me know do i need to write a custom resolver to achieve this?

Comment: Can you edit your question, and explain in a bit more detail how these Components are linked. Is it thorugh a Schema Link field or is it a link in a RTF/Format Area?

Comment: components are linked through schema link field.for e.g. - component B - Article Container has a schema field link to component C - Article component.

Answer (score 5):

There was a bug in sdl tridion CME 2013. Its working fine after applying the hotfix-

https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/hotfixes/SDL_Tridion_2013_SP1/index.aspx (login required, or contact Production Support).

Please go through below link for more info-
[Tridion Resolver not Resolving Linked Items](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/7622/tridion-resolver-not-resolving-linked-items)

Answer (score 3):

When you publish a component the resolve operation (which determines which assets get rendered, transported and deployed) will do two things:

1. Find all pages that directly or indirectly use the component
2. Find all components that the component uses directly or indirectly

This means that in your situation publishing component C will not resolve the components B and A but it will resolve any pages that components C, B or A are on as statically embedded component presentations.

The above described behaviour is the default (built-in) behaviour of Tridion; you can customize this by creating a [custom resolver](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/a-custom-resolver-in-practice)

Answer (score 3):

I do expect the Components linking to the Component you are publishing to be resolved by the standard resolvers.
However, it depends on the ResolveInstruction (which is part of the PublishInstruction).
Check the values of `ResolveInstruction.IncludeComponentLinks` and `ResolveInstruction.ResolvePurpose`.